# r markdown: data frame (or data.table) goes out of page

Tags: html, r, dataframe, r-markdown

I am trying to create an HTML output using R - markdown. The problem is that whenever I try to output any table, the formatting is very sparse. Ideally the table should be easily fitted in *one page width* but since the formatting is too sparse, one needs to scroll to the right to see the output.

Here is the code and output.

````
```{r}
df = data.frame(
  first.var = 1:10, 
  second.var = letters[1:10],
  third.var = LETTERS[1:10],
  fourth.var = paste0(letters[1:10],"-",LETTERS[1:10]),
  fifth.var = "this will not go out of screen",
  sixth.var = "but this will go out of the screen"
)
df
```
````

[image]

How can I fit more columns in one page width, so that I don't have to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the style (CSS) for the table.  I wrapped the table into `DT::datatable`:

````
<div style="width = 100%">
```{r}
df = data.frame(
  first.var = 1:10, 
  second.var = letters[1:10],
  third.var = LETTERS[1:10],
  fourth.var = paste0(letters[1:10],"-",LETTERS[1:10]),
  fifth.var = "this will not go out of screen",
  sixth.var = "but this will go out of the screen"
)
DT::datatable(df)
```
</div>
````

Comment: That's simple, and interactive as well. Thanks